# How can I perform where queries correctly in laravel eloquent query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Take a look at the following query:

```
    $testQuery = Customer::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);

    $testQuery
        ->where('name', 'like', '%test%')
        ->orWhere('age', '>', 22);

    dd($testQuery->toSql());
```

this produces the following SQL query:

> select * from `customers` where (`company_id` = ? and `name` like ? or
>   `age` > ?) and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null

What I am after is something like this:

> select * from `customers` where `company_id` = ? and (`name` like ? or
>   `age` > ?) and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null

How can I achieve this? i.e. the first where condition of `company_id = ?` more important than there rest of the filters on `name` and `age`?

Right now, based on how the query builder is constructing the query, I am seeing results from other company_id than the one I've specified in my query.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to use [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#parameter-grouping).

By using closures, you can tell the query builder what should be enclosed in parenthesis:

```
$testQuery = Customer::where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id)
                     ->where(
                         function ($query) {
                           $query->where('name', 'like', '%test%')
                                 ->orWhere('age', '>', 22);
                      })->get();
```